# How to find less than by decode?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

00907\. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

---

```sql
SELECT last_name
      ,salary
      ,DECODE(salary, salary <  6000, 0.36,
                      salary <  8000, 0.38,
                      salary < 10000, 0.4,
                      salary < 12000, 0.42,
                      salary < 14000, 0.44,
                      salary < 16000, 0.45) as "TAX RATE"
  FROM employees;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make your life a misery. Use `CASE` expression instead of `DECODE`.

```
select case when salary <  6000 then 0.36
            when salary <  8000 then 0.38
            ...
            when salary < 16000 then 0.45
            else null
       end as tax_rate
from employees
```

If you'd want to do it with `DECODE`, you'd use `SIGN` function (to check whether salary is less than certain amount), and then **nest** as many `DECODE`s as necessary. That *works*, but is a nightmare to maintain.

I don't have your table so I'll try to illustrate it using Scott's `emp`:

```
SQL> select ename, sal,
  2    decode(sign(sal - 1000), -1, 'less than 1000',
  3      decode(sign(sal - 1500), -1, 'less than 1500',
  4        decode(sign(sal - 2000), -1, 'less than 2000'))
  5          ) rate
  6  from emp;

ENAME             SAL RATE
---------- ---------- --------------
SMITH             840 less than 1000
ALLEN            1600 less than 2000
WARD             1250 less than 1500
JONES            2975
MARTIN           1250 less than 1500
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
SCOTT            3000
KING             5000
<snip>
```

If you compare it to `CASE`, difference is more than obvious:

```
SQL> select ename, sal,
  2    case when sal < 1000 then 'less than 1000'
  3         when sal < 1500 then 'less than 1500'
  4         when sal < 2000 then 'less than 2000'
  5    end rate
  6  from emp;

ENAME             SAL RATE
---------- ---------- --------------
SMITH             840 less than 1000
ALLEN            1600 less than 2000
WARD             1250 less than 1500
JONES            2975
MARTIN           1250 less than 1500
<snip>
```